# root user not executing commands in shell script in a remote machine

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script as given below.But it is not reading username and password.What Iam expecting form this script is to login as a normal user to a remote machine and login to root user to run some commands there.

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
  echo "user logined !";
  su root -c "
    echo Give username :;
    read username;
    echo Give password :;
    read password;
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
  ";
'
```

Comment: Why do you not log in to 10.3.2.0 as `root` to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `$`'s for the variables inside the quotes:

```
ssh -t qbadmin@10.3.2.0 '
  echo "user logined !";
  su root -c "
    echo Give username :;
    read username;
    echo Give password :;
    read password;
    echo \$username;
    echo \$password;
  ";
'
```

Otherwise, the shell created by the `ssh` command as the qbadmin user is going to perform string interpolation on `$username` and `$password` before executing the `su` command.